# Getting AJAX to work with node.js

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

I have this POST request for a registration page. It checks to see if a username is already being used by another user:

```
router.post ('/register', function(req, res) {
User.findOne({username: req.body.username}, function(err, existingUser) {
    if(existingUser) {
        req.flash('errors1', req.body.username + ' already exists.');
        return res.redirect('/register');
    }
//some more code down here if the username is unique
```

And here is the form (I'm using EJS):

```
<form method="POST" action="/register">
    <% if (errors1.length > 0) { %>
        <div class='form-group has-error'>
            <label for="username">Stock Ticker</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" id="username"/>
            <span class="help-block"><%= errors1 %></span>
        </div>
```

Basically, if the username entered is not unique, a message will appear just below the form telling the user that the username cannot be used. But this message only shows up *after* a user has hit the SUBMIT button.

How can I incorporate AJAX into this? I've never really used AJAX before, and have been going through the documentation and watching tutorials, but I just can't wrap my head around how I could incorporate AJAX into this piece of code.

Answer (score 1):

You should create new api to do the check and trigger this request when *input control*  **lose focus**,maybe the code would like this below:

**server.js:**

```
router.post ('/check_username', function(req, res) {
    //CODE:check your username 
})
```

**html**:

```
<div class='form-group has-error'>
        <label for="username">Stock Ticker</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" id="username"/>
        <span class="help-block"><%= errors1 %></span>
</div>
```

**js(Jquery):**

```
$("#username").focusout(function(){
        var value = $("#username").val();
        //CODE:send the request and display result;
        $.post('/check_username',{username:value},function(data){
        //CODE:handle result
        })
    });
```

Comment: You could also do it as the input value is changed, but I would suggest using a debounce/throttle function so that you don't get rapid fire calls to your server.

Comment: yes,trigger the request when content changed,the **debounce/throttle** is required